# docker compose networking with axios (node) error ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, axios

I have a docker compose stack with a few containers. The two in question are an extended `python:3-onbuild` container (see base image [here](https://github.com/hallooinc/python3-onbuild-nginx-node/blob/master/Dockerfile)) with a falcon webserver running and a basic `node:8.11-alpine` container that is attempting to make post requests to the python webserver. This is a simplified version of my compose file:

```yml
version: '3.6'

services:
  app: # python:3-onbuild
    ports:
      - 5000
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: infra/docker/app.Dockerfile

  lambda: # node:8.11-alpine
    ports:
      - 10000
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: infra/docker/lambda.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app
```

I know the networking is working because if I ssh into the lambda container

```bash
docker exec -it default_lambda_1 /bin/ash
```

and run `ping app` I get a response back.

```bash
$ ping app
PING app (172.18.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.184 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.4: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.141 ms
```

I can even run `ping app:5000`

```bash
ping app:5000
PING app:5000 (172.18.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.176 ms
```

I even created a `/status` endpoint on my api to attempt to work through this issue. It queries the names of all the tables in the database, so it should fail if the database isn't ready. But, if I run `curl http://app:5000/status` I get a response back with all my table names, no problem at all.

The problem only arises when my node process attempts to make a post request (using axios)

```ts
this.endpointUrl = 'http://app:5000';
const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${this.endpointUrl}/session/get`,
    data: {
        'client': 'alexa'
    },
    responseType: 'json'
};

axios(options)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
        console.log(`[SessionService][getSession]: "/session/get" responseData = ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`[SessionService][getSession]: error = ${err}`);
    });
```

I get the following error:

```bash
console.error src/index.ts:111
  VirtualConsole.on.e at project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45
   Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND app app:5000
        at Object.dispatchError (/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:65:19)
        at Request.client.on.err (/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:676:20)
        at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at Request.onRequestError (/project/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) undefined

  console.error src/index.ts:111
    axios_1.default.then.catch.err at services/Service.ts:94:25
     [SessionService][getSession]: error = Error: Network Error
```

I learned more about this `ENOTFOUND` error message from [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5436)

> getaddrinfo is by definition a DNS issue

So then, I looked into using the node `dns` packge to look up `app`

```bash
> dns.lookup('app', console.log)
GetAddrInfoReqWrap {
  callback: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  family: 0,
  hostname: 'app',
  oncomplete: [Function: onlookup],
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> null '172.18.0.3' 4
> dns.lookup('app:5000', console.log)
GetAddrInfoReqWrap {
  callback: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  family: 0,
  hostname: 'app:5000',
  oncomplete: [Function: onlookup],
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND app:5000
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'app:5000' }
```

So it looks like it can find `app` but not `app:5000`? Weird. Since finding this out, I tried changing the python webserver port to 80 so I could make the axios requests to plain ol' `http://app`, but that resulted in the same `ENOTFOUND` error.

I cannot find much information on how to fix this. One idea is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410545/docker-compose-network-link)

> the problem is that http.request uses dns.lookup instead of dns.resolve

The answer suggests using an overlay network. I don't really understand what that is, but if it is required, I'll go ahead and do that. But, I'm wondering if there is a more simple solution now that I'm using compose yml version 3.6. In any case, `dns.resolve` gives me similar output to `dns.lookup`

```bash
> dns.resolve('app', console.log)
QueryReqWrap {
  bindingName: 'queryA',
  callback: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  hostname: 'app',
  oncomplete: [Function: onresolve],
  ttl: false,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  channel: ChannelWrap {} }
> null [ '172.18.0.3' ]
> dns.resolve('app:5000', console.log)
QueryReqWrap {
  bindingName: 'queryA',
  callback: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  hostname: 'app:5000',
  oncomplete: [Function: onresolve],
  ttl: false,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  channel: ChannelWrap {} }
> { Error: queryA ENOTFOUND app:5000
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:238:19)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'queryA',
  hostname: 'app:5000' }
```

EDIT: By the way, I can make the same POST requests from the lambda container across https to the outside world (a production server running the same code as the app service)

EDIT: If I remove `http://` from the endpointUrl as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound), I get `Error: Invalid protocol: app`

EDIT: I thought it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/602) with the node-alpine base image, but changing to `node:8.11` or `node:carbon` resulted in the same DNS issue `ENOTFOUND`

EDIT: I'm sure it is not a timing issue because I'm waiting to run my tests for 100 seconds, making a test request every 10 seconds. If I skip the test step and let the container spin up like normal, I'm able to curl `app` from inside the `lambda` container far before a 100-second mark...

Comment: map that container port to a port in your network and simply do `http://localhost:port`

Comment: @yBrodsky you mean adding something like `ports: 5000:5000`? I'm not having problems hitting the docker container from my host machine. I'm having problems hitting it from another container in the same docker compose stack.

Comment: OK- new developments. Looks like a timing issue, i.e. the lambda service is trying to make requests to app too early... looking into how to fix this

Comment: OK- after 4 hours of messing with timeouts and promises, I've learned it is definitely not a timing issue...

Comment: take a look at the "link" property in your yml config file. It lets you add references to another containers

Comment: links have been deprecated https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with my test runner, jest.

> The default environment in Jest is a browser-like environment through jsdom. If you are building a node service, you can use the node option to use a node-like environment instead.

To fix this I had to add this in my jest.config.js file:

```
{
  // ...
  testEnvironment: 'node'
  // ...
}
```

Source: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1418